# Is there any documentation for JHipster needles?

Tags: jhipster

I am looking for a way to customize a scaffold generated by JHipster as easily as possible. Following the idea of the talk [side-by-side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo).

I have found many JHipster-needle hints in the generated Source Code. They are very helpful to see where to insert extensions.

For example the Needle

```
/* jhipster-needle-add-entity-route - JHipster will add entity modules routes here */
```

in the class `entity-routing-module.ts` tells me that where to add a new entity module and the needle

```
<!-- jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-menu - JHipster will add entities to the menu here -->
```

in the html-template `navbar.component.html` tells me where to add the new entity in the menu.

Is there an official guide on how to use the needles? I'm not writing a Blueprint or JHipster modules, but I'd still like to find uncomplicated places to extend the scaffold.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such doc

Comment: This really needs an answer or documentation. I'm eager to contribute more documentation and looking for something to build out this more. These `jhipster-needle-...` comments appear also in the `pom.xml` and using such needles to add repositories would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such documentation. But you can use JHipster [blueprints](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/) to extend the scaffolding.
In the blueprint you can explicitly call the needle APIs based on the file which you want to extend, for e.g. Angular, React, Liquibase, etc.

For e.g. If you you want to add a new Angular route and menu item for the entity, you would call the below APIs in the [writing](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-nodejs/blob/main/generators/client/index.js#L72) lifecycle hook of your blueprint:

1. `this.needleApi.clientAngular.addEntityToModule()`
2. `this.needleApi.clientAngular.addEntityToMenu()`

Similarly, there are lot more clients and you can use them based on which file you want to extend. Code pointer: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v7.9.3/generators/needle-api.js

Needle API classes for the frontend(client) code: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/v7.9.3/generators/client/needle-api